# How to control the originating IPv6 of emails sent by postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, ipv6, spf

In a VPS with 2 `IPv4` and 16 `IPv6`, I send emails with `postfix`. Each time, the email is sent from one of the IPs randomly

```
Received: from domain.com (a random IPv6 out of my 16 IPv6)
```

Thus, `SPF` fails (of course, softfail), as the originating IP is not in my DNS record. I can set a range of IP in DNS's SPF record, but how can I tell postfix to submit email from the main IP (the one I set rDNS)?

Answer (score 3):

There are two options available for binding smtp client to particular IPs/IPv6s ([man 5 postconf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/postconf)):

- `smtp_bind_address`
- `smtp_bind_address6`

I think they are pretty self-descriptive. Just make sure that related NICs/IPs are defined by `inet_interfaces` option.

By the way, SPF records support multiple originating IP addresses per domain. Try to generate it with [this SPF wizard](http://www.unlocktheinbox.com/spfwizard/). Just a quick example:

```
domain.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:1.2.3.4 a:1.2.3.5 a:1.2.3.6 ~all"
domain.com. IN SPF "v=spf1 a mx a:1.2.3.4 a:1.2.3.5 a:1.2.3.6 ~all"
```

Comment: You can also allow mail from the whole IPv6 subnet. For example:  ip6:2001:db8:12ab:34cd::/64